# fill path of svg icons is not working on Safari but on Chrome

Tags: jquery, svg, fill

[image]I am desperately looking for a solution why Chrome is displaying my svg icons correctly (in the correct color) and Safari not.

Any improvements or hints are appreciated.

Please ask if something remains unclear about my issue

Thanks!

```
  Script for transforming svg into inline svg 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function() {
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
            var attributes = $img.prop("attributes");

        $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Remove any invalid XML tags
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Loop through IMG attributes and apply on SVG
        $.each(attributes, function() {
            $svg.attr(this.name, this.value);
        });

        // Replace IMG with SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);
            }, 'xml');
        });
        });
    </script>


    HTML code

    <div id="icon-bar">  
    <ul id="navbaricons">
        <li><a href="index.html"><img src="bildernavbar/Logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="22" height="23"></a></li> 
        <li><a href="search.html"><img src="bildernavbar/search.svg" alt="Search" width="21" height="23"></a></li>
        <li><a href="like.html"><img src="bildernavbar/heart.svg" alt="Heart" width="23" height="23"></a></li>
        <li><a href="annonce.html"><img  src="bildernavbar/annonce.svg" alt="upload" width="35" height="23"></a></li>
        <li><a id="profile" href="profile.html"><img src="bildernavbar/user.svg" alt="Profil" width="23" height="23"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


CSS

#navbaricons path {
    fill: #323b4a;
}

#navbaricons:hover path {
    fill: white;
}
```

Comment: We probably need to see the DOM after it's been processed by the loading function.

Comment: I am a beginner... so how exactly do I show you the DOM?

Comment: The browser's DOM inspector or debugger.

Comment: Or at the very least, post the contents of one of the SVGs that are not working.

Comment: I added an image which shows my debugger. I hope this helps to understand my problem. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help at all. I wanted the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). Or as Paul asked for, the contents of one or more of the SVG files.

Comment: You may need to test your website by hosting it on a local webserver, rather than using `file://` URLs.

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to explicitly set the height and width attributes explicitly on the SVG element for it to display correctly on Safari. Both absolute values and percentages seem to work.

```html
<svg viewport="..." height="100%" width="100%">...</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the SVGs set their fill colours using the `style` attribute?  For example:

```
style="fill: red"
```

`style` attributes have higher precedence than CSS rules. Compare the two rectangles in the following example.

```css
rect {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill: red"/>
  <rect x="120" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

To fix this, take any properties you want to style with CSS, and either:

- remove them from the `style` attribute completely, or
- change them to presentation attributes. Eg. `fill="red"`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me.